# How do I run apps in an emulator running in another computer in my network, where my computer running android-studio is connected?

Tags: android, android-studio, networking, android-emulator, connection

I have just 4gb of ram available on my computer, where I run android-studio/intellij/(sometimes) eclipse.
So it is not feasible to run the emulator at the same time.

I also happen to have an old laptop (with 2gb ram), which can run android in virtual box quite well.

So I want to run/test my android apps on that laptop from my computer. (PS: the two computers are connected together via LAN).

What I thought I would do is : to write a python script with which everytime the app apk is build, I will send the apk to the laptop and run the app via adb in the emulator.

**So how do I run the apps on the emulator running on another laptop over the network?**

Comment: http://codetheory.in/android-debug-bridge-adb-wireless-debugging-over-wi-fi/
refer this link to connect your phone wireless to any computer

Comment: This applies for virtual machines too, right?

Comment: First, install ADB and on Linux or Mac or Windows computer and connect your devices with a wireless network I am already using ADB in my windows10.

Comment: I never try this on a virtual machine

Comment: The android is running as virtual machine.
It's running in another laptop, which is connected to my computer (Desktop) via LAN.
I want to run my apps on that emulator (running on the laptop).